# parse time in dateBox(), or eliminate time in datebox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to parse the time in dateBox(), or better yet eliminate it all together? I want  someone to be able to use the dateBox() to choose the date only, but want to get rid of the time and use another function I create for the time.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

one simple way of doing this is like this :

```
var date = new Date(e.parameter.start);// convert the string to a full date object (with time value) (the date widget is named 'start' in this example)
var dateOnly = date.setHours(0,0,0,0); // set time to '0' (hours,min,sec,millisec)or use the hours and minutes you get from elsewhere...
```

You can have a look at [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dEFnZzNIMG1udUpIcUdaNGhUeEU4cXc) where I use this to combine data from 2 columns (date and time) to create a complete date object